# Custom DataGridViewRow issue: Getting custom property is always default value (false)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make some custom `DataGridViewRow` for styling purposes, and to implement a custom expand/collapse row system.

I've tried a basic row class skeleton like this:

```
class MyRow : DataGridViewRow
{
    public Boolean IsChild;
}
```

And a custom `DataGridView` like this:

```
    public partial class MyGrid : DataGridView
{
    public MyGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RowTemplate = new MyRow();
    }
}
```

Then in my `Form` I'm using it like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myGrid1.Rows.Add(new MyRow());
    myGrid1.Rows.Add(new MyRow() { IsChild = true });
    myGrid1.Rows.Add(new MyRow() { IsChild = true });

    for (int i = 0; i < myGrid1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        MyRow r;

        if (myGrid1.Rows[i] is MyRow)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(":)");
            r = (MyRow)myGrid1.Rows[i]; // r = myGrid1.Rows[i] as MyRow;
        }
        else
        {
            continue; // It's ok, we never run this part
        }

        if (r.IsChild) // Never true
        {
            r.Visible = false;

            MessageBox.Show(":C"); // Never prints this
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in the comments I'm not able to get the boolean that will tell me whether a row is child or not. I'm always getting the default value (false) during the cast I suppose.

I think I need to change the `DataGridView.Rows` collection to a list of `MyRow` instead of `DataGridViewRow`, so that I can avoid the casting. The problem is that I don't know absolutely how to do it.. I tried to make a `List<MyRow>` but that won't work because of compatibility with `DataGridViewRowCollection`, then I tried to inherit from it, nothing.

I will supply some examples for that, but I'd like to know first if it's worth to try that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), what you need when you derive from `DataGridViewRow` and then add new properties to the derived class, is to override the `Clone` method to copy the new properties during cloning operations.

I just tested your code and it works fine after adding the clone method.

```
class MyRow : DataGridViewRow
{

    public bool IsChild { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        var clonedRow = base.Clone() as MyRow;
        clonedRow.IsChild = this.IsChild;
        return clonedRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's good to know how to do it for later. However I solved the problem by adding another class called DataGridViewRowChild, and testing for (row is DataGridViewRowChild) and that worked.
I need that class to be different from a row parent, as they will have different methods.